# How can I query _id from my MongoDB collection using GraphQL?

Tags: go, graphql

can someone help with graphql and mongo. How can I query _id from db for my model?

**1) My schema.**

```
type Course {
  title: String!
  description: String
  class_id: ID!
}
```

**2) My model.**

```
type Course struct {
    Title       string  `json:"title"`
    Description *string `json:"description,omitempty"`
    ClassID     string  `json:"class_id"`
}
```

**3) My resolver.**

```golang
// GetCourses is the resolver for the getCourses field.
func (r *queryResolver) GetCourses(ctx context.Context) ([]*model.Course, error) {
    cursor, err := courseColl.Find(ctx, bson.D{})

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("courses not found")
    }
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    var courses []*model.Course
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var course model.Course
        if err := cursor.Decode(&course); err != nil {
            continue
        }
        courses = append(courses, &course)
    }

    if err := cursor.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return courses, nil
}
```

I need to query _id here
[image]

I am wondering if I should to add _id field to my schema but I do not have exactly a clue